# glicth or black screen shown at the end of the screen in flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies, flutter-animation

"In my Flutter code for the home screen, there's an issue where a glitch or black screen appears at the bottom when navigating to or returning from the list view screen. Could someone help me address this problem?"

```
import 'dart:async';

import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart';
import 'package:firebase_database/firebase_database.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_screenutil/flutter_screenutil.dart';
import 'package:google_fonts/google_fonts.dart';
import 'package:google_sign_in/google_sign_in.dart';
import 'package:grocery_app/screens/signup_screen.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';

import '../model/groceryList_model.dart';
import '../model/home_loading_provider.dart';
import '../model/search_provider.dart';
import '../widgets/constants.dart';
import '../widgets/dialogs.dart';
import 'add_list.dart';
import 'auth/authentication.dart';
import 'list_view.dart';

class HomeScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  const HomeScreen({super.key});

  @override
  State<HomeScreen> createState() => _HomeScreenState();
}

class _HomeScreenState extends State<HomeScreen> {
  final DatabaseReference dbRef =
      FirebaseDatabase.instance.ref().child('GroceryLists');

  bool isChecked = false; // Checkbox state
  Color _getColorFromID(dynamic colorID) {
    try {
      int index = int.parse(colorID?.toString() ?? '0');
      if (index >= 0 && index < AddList.selectedThemeColors.length) {
        return AddList.selectedThemeColors[index];
      } else {
        return Colors.grey; // Return default color if index is out of range
      }
    } catch (e) {
      return Colors.grey; // Default color in case of an error
    }
  }

  final databaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.instance.ref();

  //bool isLoading = true;
  List<GroceryList> groceryLists = [];

  //bool _isSearching = false; // Whether the search mode is active or not
  TextEditingController _searchController = TextEditingController();

  // This below function returns all the lists data and shown on the screen here the condition i added
  // to check the userID if its matched then shown the lists otherwise not shown the lists
  void showData() async {
    final homeLoadingProvider =
        Provider.of<HomeLoadingProvider>(context, listen: false);
    homeLoadingProvider.setLoading(true); // Set loading to true initially

    final processedLists = Set<String>();
    // Check if there is any data in the 'GroceryLists' node initially
    await databaseReference.child('GroceryLists').get().then((snapshot) async {
      if (snapshot.value == null) {
        homeLoadingProvider.setLoading(false);
        return; // Return early if there's no data
      }
    });
    // Get the current user
    User? user = FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser;
    //print('user : ${user}');

    // Check if the user is logged in and get their UID
    if (user != null) {
      String currentUid = user.uid;
      //print('currentUid : ${currentUid}');
      databaseReference
          .child('GroceryLists')
          .onChildAdded
          .listen((event) async {
        try {
          var groceryListKey = event.snapshot.key;
          var value = event.snapshot.value;

          if (value is Map<dynamic, dynamic>) {
            Map<String, dynamic> groceryListValue =
                Map<String, dynamic>.from(value);
            String? listName = groceryListValue['listName'] as String?;
            String? listId = groceryListValue['id'] as String?;
            String? userId =
                groceryListValue['Members'][currentUid]['userId'] as String?;
            // print('userId inside Members node : ${userId}');

            if (listName != null &&
                listId != null &&
                userId == currentUid && // Check if userId matches currentUid
                !processedLists.contains(listName)) {
              processedLists.add(listName);
              var itemValueMap = await fetchItemsForList(groceryListKey!);
              //print('itemValueMap : ${itemValueMap}');
              var colorID = groceryListValue['colorID'] ?? "";

              List<String> simpleItems = [];
              List<bool> isCheckedItems = [];

              if (itemValueMap.isNotEmpty) {
                itemValueMap.forEach((key, itemValue) {
                  if (itemValue is Map<dynamic, dynamic> &&
                      itemValue['category'] is Map) {
                    var categoryItems = itemValue['category']['item'] as List?;
                    var categoryName =
                        itemValue['category']['categoryName'] as String?;

                    if (categoryItems != null && categoryName != "Done") {
                      for (var item in categoryItems) {
                        if (item is Map) {
                          String? itemName = item['itemName'] as String?;

                          if (itemName != null) {
                            simpleItems.add(itemName);

                            // Check if the item is marked as done in "Done" category
                            var doneCategory = itemValueMap.entries.firstWhere(
                                (entry) => (entry.value['category']
                                        ['categoryName'] ==
                                    "Done"),
                                orElse: () => MapEntry(
                                    null, {}) // returning dummy MapEntry here
                                );

                            bool isDone = false;
                            if (doneCategory.key != null) {
                              var doneItems = doneCategory.value['category']
                                  ['item'] as List?;
                              var doneItem = doneItems?.firstWhere(
                                  (doneItem) =>
                                      doneItem['itemName'] == itemName,
                                  orElse: () => null);
                              isDone = doneItem != null &&
                                  doneItem['isDone'] == true;
                            }

                            isCheckedItems.add(isDone);
                          }
                        }
                      }
                    }
                  }
                });
                String? createdAtString =
                    groceryListValue['createdAt'] as String?;
                DateTime? createdAt = createdAtString != null
                    ? DateTime.parse(createdAtString)
                    : DateTime.now();
                if (simpleItems.length == isCheckedItems.length) {
                  groceryLists.add(GroceryList(
                    listName: listName,
                    items: simpleItems,
                    colorID: colorID,
                    id: listId,
                    isChecked: isCheckedItems,
                    createdAt: createdAt, // Add this line
                  ));
                  groceryLists.sort((a, b) => b.createdAt.compareTo(
                      a.createdAt)); // sorting in descending order of createdAt
                  setState(() {});
                }
              }
            }
          }
          // Set isLoading to false when the processing for this child is done.
          homeLoadingProvider.setLoading(false);
        } catch (e) {
          print("Error while processing grocery list data: $e");
          homeLoadingProvider.setLoading(false);
        }
      });
    } else {
      print('user has not logged in till now');
    }
  }

  Future<Map<dynamic, dynamic>> fetchItemsForList(String groceryListKey) async {
    var itemsSnapshot = await databaseReference
        .child('GroceryLists/$groceryListKey/items')
        .get();
    if (itemsSnapshot.value is Map<dynamic, dynamic>) {
      return itemsSnapshot.value as Map<dynamic, dynamic>;
    }
    return {};
  }

  late List<GroceryList> displayedGroceryLists;
  List<GroceryList> filterGroceryLists(String query) {
    if (query.isEmpty) {
      return groceryLists; // return all items if query is empty
    }

    return groceryLists.where((groceryList) {
      // Check if the listName matches the query
      if (groceryList.listName.toLowerCase().contains(query.toLowerCase())) {
        return true;
      }

      // Check if any of the items in the list match the query
      for (var itemName in groceryList.items) {
        if (itemName.toLowerCase().contains(query.toLowerCase())) {
          return true;
        }
      }

      return false; // if neither listName nor any itemName matches
    }).toList();
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    //showData();
    WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((_) => showData());
    displayedGroceryLists = groceryLists;
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _searchController.dispose(); // Dispose of the TextEditingController
    //groceryListsController.close();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Consumer<SearchProvider>(builder: (context, searchProvider, child) {
      return Scaffold(
        backgroundColor: Colors.white,
        appBar: !searchProvider.isSearching
            ? AppBar(
                backgroundColor: Colors.green,
                toolbarHeight: 80.h,
                leadingWidth: 262.w,
                leading: Padding(
                  padding: EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 0, left: 20.w, top: 40.h),
                  child: Text(
                    'My Lists',
                    style: GoogleFonts.jost(
                      fontSize: 20.sp,
                      fontWeight: FontWeight.w500,
                      color: Colors.white,
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
                actions: [
                  Padding(
                    padding: EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 0, left: 10.w, top: 30.h),
                    child: Row(
                      children: [
                        IconButton(
                          onPressed: () {
                            searchProvider
                                .toggleSearch(); // Use Provider to toggle search state
                          },
                          icon: Icon(Icons.search_sharp,
                              color: Colors.white, size: 24.sp),
                        ),
                        SizedBox(width: 15.w),
                        PopupMenuButton(
                          icon: Icon(Icons.more_vert,
                              color: Colors.white, size: 24.sp),
                          itemBuilder: (BuildContext context) =>
                              <PopupMenuEntry>[
                            PopupMenuItem(
                              child: Container(
                                width: 100.w,
                                height: 110.h,
                                child: Column(
                                  children: [
                                    Row(
                                      children: [
                                        Icon(Icons.star,
                                            size: 24.sp, color: Colors.black),
                                        SizedBox(width: 10.w),
                                        Text(
                                          'Rate App',
                                          style: GoogleFonts.jost(
                                            fontWeight: FontWeight.w400,
                                            fontSize: 14.sp,
                                            color: Color(0xff292D32),
                                          ),
                                        ),
                                      ],
                                    ),
                                    SizedBox(height: 10.h),
                                    Row(
                                      children: [
                                        Icon(Icons.share,
                                            size: 24.sp, color: Colors.black),
                                        SizedBox(width: 10.w),
                                        Text(
                                          'Share App',
                                          style: GoogleFonts.jost(
                                            fontWeight: FontWeight.w400,
                                            fontSize: 14.sp,
                                            color: Color(0xff292D32),
                                          ),
                                        ),
                                      ],
                                    ),
                                    Container(
                                      width: double.infinity,
                                      child: Divider(
                                        color: Color(0xffD2D2D2),
                                        thickness: 1,
                                      ),
                                    ),
                                    InkWell(
                                      onTap: () async {
                                        Dialogs.showProgressBar(context);
                                        await AuthServices.firebaseAuth
                                            .signOut()
                                            .then((value) async {
                                          await GoogleSignIn()
                                              .signOut()
                                              .then((value) {
                                            // //for hiding progress dialog
                                            // Navigator.pop(context);

                                            //for moving to Sign Up screen
                                            Navigator.pop(
                                                context); // This pops the progress dialog

                                            AuthServices.firebaseAuth =
                                                FirebaseAuth.instance;

                                            //replacing home screen with login screen
                                            Navigator.pushReplacement(
                                                context,
                                                MaterialPageRoute(
                                                    builder: (_) =>
                                                        SignupScreen()));
                                          });
                                        });
                                      },
                                      child: Row(
                                        children: [
                                          Icon(
                                            Icons.logout,
                                            size: 24.sp,
                                            color: Color(0xffE93333),
                                          ),
                                          SizedBox(width: 10.w),
                                          Text(
                                            'Logout',
                                            style: GoogleFonts.jost(
                                              fontWeight: FontWeight.w400,
                                              fontSize: 14.sp,
                                              color: Color(0xffE93333),
                                            ),
                                          ),
                                        ],
                                      ),
                                    )
                                  ],
                                ),
                              ),
                            ),
                          ],
                        ),
                        SizedBox(width: 20.w),
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              )
            : PreferredSize(
                preferredSize: Size.fromHeight(80.h),
                child: Padding(
                  padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 40.h),
                  child: TextField(
                    controller: _searchController,
                    onChanged: (value) {
                      setState(() {
                        displayedGroceryLists = filterGroceryLists(value);
                      });
                    },
                    autofocus: true,
                    decoration: InputDecoration(
                      hintText: "Search your notes",
                      hintStyle: GoogleFonts.jost(
                        color: Color(0xFF9F9F9F),
                        fontWeight: FontWeight.w400,
                        fontSize: 14.sp,
                        letterSpacing: 0.15,
                      ),
                      border: InputBorder.none,
                      focusedBorder: UnderlineInputBorder(
                        borderSide: BorderSide(color: Color(0xFFD2D2D2)),
                      ),
                      enabledBorder: UnderlineInputBorder(
                        borderSide: BorderSide(color: Color(0xFFD2D2D2)),
                      ),
                      prefixIcon: IconButton(
                        icon: Icon(Icons.arrow_back, color: Color(0xff292D32)),
                        onPressed: () {
                          searchProvider.closeSearch();
                        },
                      ), // Optional: To further ensure padding consistency
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
        floatingActionButton: Container(
          height: 40.h,
          width: 158.w,
          child: FloatingActionButton(
            backgroundColor: Colors.green,
            shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(27),
            ),
            onPressed: () {
              showDialog(
                context: context,
                builder: (BuildContext context) => AddListDialog(),
              );
            },
            child: Row(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
              children: [
                Flexible(
                  child: Icon(
                    Icons.add,
                    color: Colors.white,
                    size: 24.sp,
                  ),
                ),
                Flexible(
                  child: Text(
                    'Create',
                    style: GoogleFonts.jost(
                      fontSize: 16.sp,
                      fontWeight: FontWeight.w500,
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ),
        body: SafeArea(
          child: Column(
            children: [
              Expanded(
                child: Consumer<HomeLoadingProvider>(
                  builder: (context, homeLoadingProvider, child) {
                    return homeLoadingProvider.isLoading
                        ? Center(
                            child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
                          )
                        : groceryLists.isEmpty
                            ? Center(
                                child: Column(
                                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                                  children: [
                                    Image.asset('assets/images/empty_home.png',
                                        width: 205.w, height: 171.h),
                                    Container(
                                      alignment: Alignment.center,
                                      height: 50.h,
                                      width: 288.w,
                                      child: Text(
                                        'You don’t have any shopping lists right now. Please create one from the button below.',
                                        style: GoogleFonts.jost(
                                          fontSize: 14.sp,
                                          fontWeight: FontWeight.w400,
                                          letterSpacing: 0.15,
                                          color: Color(0xff292D32),
                                        ),
                                      ),
                                    ),
                                  ],
                                ),
                              )
                            : GridView.builder(
                                padding: EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                                gridDelegate:
                                    SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(
                                  crossAxisCount: 2,
                                  mainAxisSpacing: 8.0,
                                  crossAxisSpacing: 8.0,
                                  childAspectRatio:
                                      0.7, // Adjust this value to control the card's height
                                ),
                                itemCount: displayedGroceryLists.length,
                                itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                                  final displayedList =
                                      displayedGroceryLists[index];
                                  return GestureDetector(
                                    onTap: () {
                                      Navigator.push(
                                        context,
                                        MaterialPageRoute(
                                          builder: (context) => ListViewScreen(
                                            groceryListName:
                                                displayedList.listName,
                                            listId: displayedList.id,
                                            cardColor: _getColorFromID(
                                                displayedList.colorID),
                                          ),
                                        ),
                                      );
                                    },
                                    child: Card(
                                      color: _getColorFromID(
                                          displayedList.colorID),
                                      child: Padding(
                                        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                                        child: Column(
                                          crossAxisAlignment:
                                              CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                                          children: [
                                            Text(
                                              displayedList.listName,
                                              style: TextStyle(
                                                fontSize: 18.sp,
                                                fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                              ),
                                            ),
                                            SizedBox(height: 5.h),
                                            Expanded(
                                              child: ListView.builder(
                                                itemCount:
                                                    displayedList.items.length,
                                                shrinkWrap: true,
                                                itemBuilder:
                                                    (context, itemIndex) {
                                                  return Padding(
                                                    padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                                                        vertical: 7
                                                            .h), // added padding for spacing between items
                                                    child: Row(
                                                      children: [
                                                        SizedBox(
                                                          height: 16.h,
                                                          width: 16.w,
                                                          child: Checkbox(
                                                            value: displayedList
                                                                    .isChecked[
                                                                itemIndex],
                                                            onChanged: null,
                                                            activeColor: Color(
                                                                0xff9F9F9F),
                                                            checkColor:
                                                                Colors.white,
                                                            materialTapTargetSize:
                                                                MaterialTapTargetSize
                                                                    .shrinkWrap,
                                                          ),
                                                        ),
                                                        SizedBox(width: 5.w),
                                                        Expanded(
                                                          child: Text(
                                                            displayedList.items[
                                                                itemIndex],
                                                            style: TextStyle(
                                                              fontSize: 14.sp,
                                                              decoration: displayedList
                                                                          .isChecked[
                                                                      itemIndex]
                                                                  ? TextDecoration
                                                                      .lineThrough
                                                                  : null,
                                                            ),
                                                          ),
                                                        ),
                                                      ],
                                                    ),
                                                  );
                                                },
                                              ),
                                            ),
                                          ],
                                        ),
                                      ),
                                    ),
                                  );
                                },
                              );
                  },
                ),
              )
            ],
          ),
        ),
      );
    });
  }
}
```

I am not getting any solution i try a lots but the issue is still persist please any one solve this

Comment: What is the parent widget of `ListViewScreen`?

Comment: no parent widget for Listview Screeen. Listview screen is a Stateful widget